# How to get data inside a function with multiple request

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm having trouble to get the `id_one` and `id_two` to add on my body on the third request. The first and second request are successful. Below are the demonstration of my single function with multiple api request. Actually if I `console.log(one or two)` it will display the `id_one` and `id_two` however when I try to use it inside the `reqThreeApi` it gives me an `undefined` error for both `id_one` and `id_two`.

```
const handleAction = async (props) => {
    reqOneApi(
            body,
            res => { setOne(res.data.id_one) },
            err => { err.response.data) }
        )
    reqTwoApi(
        body,
        res => { setTwo(res.data.id_two) },
        err => { err.response.data) }
    )
    reqThreeApi(
        { setOne_id: setOne, setTwo_id: setTwo },
        res => { console.log('get setOne and setTwo', res.data) },
        err => { err.response.data)} }
    )
};
```

Comment: What are `setOne` and `setTwo`? React `useState` setters? You may need to place `reqThreeApi` into an `useEffect` hook with dependency `[one, two]` and when both values are set, fire off the third request. The other pattern is to await the resolved values of the first two API calls (*handleAction is already async function*) to have those values available to make the third API call. Can you update your question to include all three functions?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an async function and the calls down the line depend upon calls before it, You should definitely await them and it'll fix this.

```js
const handleAction = async (props) => {
    await reqOneApi(
            body,
            res => { setOne(res.data.id_one) },
            err => { err.response.data) }
        )
    await reqTwoApi(
        body,
        res => { setTwo(res.data.id_two) },
        err => { err.response.data) }
    )
    await reqThreeApi(
        { setOne_id: setOne, setTwo_id: setTwo },
        res => { console.log('get setOne and setTwo', res.data) },
        err => { err.response.data)} }
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your third API call your just passing a reference to your set functions. You will need to either call your set functions instead of just passing them as a references or storing their value in a variable and then pass that variable to your third api.